# Handle Multiple APIs simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I want to call two apis simultaneously. And the case is, when i got successful response of both apis, then only third api should be called. Here i won't use any flag or variable to check if both apis are successful. Please suggest if there is any way to do that.

Comment: Why won't you use a flag?

Comment: Because It is not proper way to do that. Any variable shall not be used for just checking both api responses came or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DispatchGroup`

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
perform(request: first) {
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
perform(request: second) {
    group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("both done")
}
```

Comment: That's It. Thanks. :)

Comment: @DhavalTrivedi You can approve my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use Dispatch group to create a group of tasks

here example

```
// First, we create a group to synchronize our tasks
let group = DispatchGroup()

// The 'enter' method increments the group's task count…
group.enter()

ApiRequest1.Data { data in
    // …while the 'leave' methods decrements it
    group.leave()
}
group.enter

ApiRequest2.Data { data in
    group.leave()
}

// This closure will be called when the group's task count reaches 0
group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Its working fine.